# Using 2 Controller Functions in a View in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to have two loops in my view, so I wrote these two functions

```
public function index()
{
    $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
    return view('bookpage')->with('books', $books);
}

public function loggedin()
    {
        $books = Book::orderBy('RAND()')->take(1)->get();
        return view('bookpage')->with('books', $books);

    }
```

In the `view` I have

```
<!--First Loop -->   
    @foreach($books as $book)
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="out-box">
              <h2>{{ $book->name }}</h2>
              <h3>{{ $book->author->name }}</h3>
              <br>
              <a href="#" class="start-btn">Start Reading</a><br><br>
              <a href="#" class="buy-btn"><img src="assets/img/cart-buy.png" width="13px"/>&nbsp; Buy</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="aboutbook" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
        <label for="aboutbook" class="aboutbook">About This Book</label>
        <input id="bookreview" type="radio" name="tabs">
        <label for="bookreview" class="bookreview">Reviews</label>
        <hr style="background-color:black;">
        <section style="padding-top:5px;" id="bookabout" >
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{ $book -> about }}</p>
              <h1>About the Author</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-6">
              <img src="assets/img/Ellipse.png" class="rounded-circle" width="120px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-6">
              <h1>{{ $book->author->name }}</h1>
              <h4>{{ $book->author->about }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-5">
              <div id="learnbtn">
                <a href="#" class="learn-btn">Learn More</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section style="padding-top:5px;" id="bookabout1" >
          jjjjjjj
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      @endforeach
</section>

<!--Second Loop -->   
    @foreach($books as $book)
      @if($book->recommended === 1)

      <div class="col-1-5">
        <div class="home-catalog-image">
        <a href="{{ $book->image_url }}" target="_blank">
      <!--  <img src="{{ $book->image }}" alt="trending image" /> -->
        <img src="{{ $book->image_url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ $book->image_url }}">

        </a>

      <!-- <img src="{{ asset('/books/'.$book->image) }}" alt="trending image" /> -->
        </div>
        <p class="author">{{ $book->author->name }}</p>
        <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($book -> name, 20) }}</h1>
      </div>
      @endif 

      @endforeach
```

In my web.php
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');

I want to call another function in the view, although I know the method is wrong,  I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Use different varialbe name for both and use isset condition to check if var is exists

Comment: From your code it seems you are using 2nd method for logged in users only, is that the case?

Comment: Yes, the second method is for logged in user

Comment: For that just use `if(Auth()->user()){}` condition in you first method

Comment: Divyant - Can you please explain what you meant, either by code or something understandable,  thanks.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: I am using laravel 6.0

Comment: Checkout below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem like this

```
    public function loggedin()
{
        $data = array();
        $data['recommends'] = Book::where('recommended', 1)->take(10)->get();
        $data['latests'] = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc',)->where('recommended', 0)->take(10)->get();
        $data['logged'] = Book::all()->random(1);
       return view('index-logged', compact("data"));

    }
```

In my view, I did

```
    @foreach($data['logged'] as $log)
          <h1>{{ $log->author->name }}</h1>
          <h4>{{ $log->author->about }}</h4>
    @endforeach

@foreach($data['recommends'] as $recommend)
       <p class="author">{{ $recommend->author->name }}</p>
        <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($recommend -> name, 20) }}</h1>
@endforeach

@foreach($data['latests'] as $latest)
    <p class="author">{{ $latest->author->name }}</p>
    <h1 class="book-title">{{str_limit($latest -> name, 20) }}</h1>
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create two different method for logged in user just use

```
public function index()
{
      if(auth()->user()) {
            $books = Book::orderBy('RAND()')->take(1)->get();
      } else $books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
    return view('bookpage')->with('books', $books);
}
```

in view file use

```
@auth
      //code for logged in user
@else
      //code for guest user
@endauth
```

Comment: The issue with this is that there are other sections on the page that are the same for every user (logged in and not logged in).

I will still need this code for that to display the information in order sections

$books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
    return view('bookpage')->with('books', $books);


When the user is not logged in, the slider is just about the company, when the user is logged in, I want to display a single book randomly from the database.

Thats why I am using the RAND method. Hope you understand my problem now

Comment: You won't need condition in view for those code blocks, you will get respective data from Controller for both guest and logged in user, use condtion only when section is different for user in view file